How to remove handle from vintage sink?
I bought an older pedestal sink thinking it would be just switching out supply lines but there's a constant leak stream from the faucet when I turn on the hot water even though the handle is in the off position. So I think the issue is in the handle itself but I can't for the life of me get the handle off. I don't see any screws, I removed it as far as I could but now this is what it looks like. Any advice on getting this handle completely off?
Handle picture so far:


These handles should have a screw under the button on the top that has an H or C on it. Usually a Phillips head screw.
The buttons just press into the top of the handle but can be pried out  with a small flat blade screw driver or the edge of a sharp knife. Then you can remove the screw and the handle will come off of the base.
Then you should be able to replace the washers in the handle or remove and replace the entire handle set.

Wow, a secret button! Would not have thought of that. Thank you so much!!

Can I bother you one more time since you are so knowledgeable? https://imgur.com/fTFATbm What do I do next? haha

If there isn’t a hole with an Allen screw in the side of the base I would try unscrewing the chrome base part counter clockwise while holding the stem part from below.

@cal Those are normally screwed on. I find a rubber strap wrench is really helpful for getting a grip on the top part. When re-installing, finger-tight is fine.

It's possible the "fairing" is corroded to the valve.  Tapping on the top of the valve with a rubber mallet or a wooden block with a hammer may free it.  Otherwise, perhaps an angle grinder or sawzall with a metals blade to simply cut through the threaded barrel of the valve below the fairing.
